# Is there better JavaScript code for validating a string as Date-Time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date

I'm using a CustomValidator in an ASP.NET page to validate the text in a TextBox as a Date-Time.  I'm expecting pretty much only one format, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM PM".  The TextBox is usually expecting to be filled by an associated DatePicker, but the user may still freeform it if they want.

Heres' the code, which seems to work.  I am looking to see if there is any better JavaScript for this purpose.

```
function StartDateTimeValidate(source, args)
{
    var d = Date.parse(args.Value);
    if (isNaN(d))
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDateCalendarTextBox" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="StartDateCustomValidator" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Bad Date" 
    ClientValidationFunction="StartDateTimeValidate"  
    ValidateEmptyText="false" 
    ControlToValidate="StartDateCalendarTextBox"
    ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin JavaScript Date object is based upon a old Java object which is pretty limited.

A lot of projects i run into use moment.js for any date manipulation or validation.

http://momentjs.com/

If you don't want to go with moment.js, your isNaN() approach is probably the best. Otherwise you'd have to write some kind of date parsing yourself to validate the Date.

Comment: Thanks for the info on moment.js.  I will check it out!